# HTTP PATCH: Proper JSON Patch notation for adding to empty array

Tags: arrays, json, api, architecture, http-patch

Given something like the following JSON:

```
{
    "pageId": 2,
    "page_title": "My page",
    "order": 1,
    "active": true,
    "layout": null,
    "unitId": 1,
    "mediaContainers": [
    
    ]
  },
```

What is the proper way to add an item to the `mediaContainers` array using the [JSON Patch](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902#appendix-A.2) notation? I've tried

```
{
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/mediaContainers/-",
    "value": {
        "type": "video",
        "mediaContainerVideos": []
    }
}
```

and

```
{
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/mediaContainers/0",
    "value": {
        "type": "video",
        "mediaContainerVideos": []
    }
}
```

with no success, which makes sense now since this array is empty. From what I've seen in the spec, all the examples deal with non-empty arrays, so I'm at a bit of a loss here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way according to a specification (despite there are no examples with empty arrays) is to go with "-": `/mediaContainers/-`.

> with no success

I think this is a bug of the library you are using since the specs [here](http://jsonpatch.com/) say "The - character can be used instead of an index to insert at the end of an array.". Empty arrays are no exclusion to that.

Comment: It was indeed a bug with the library I was using!